# Mahout and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, mahout

I use a Mahout (version 0.8) and MySQL.
I can not figure out how to connect to the database. The examples use a MySQLJDBCDataModel, but this class is not in the package.

This is because the version still in development? Or is now the new way to connect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it certainly is in the project. Look in `mahout-integration`.